# Xcode linker error: ld: library not found for -twsapi

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have compiled and installed a library using Makefile for `i386` architecture. The library is located in `/usr/local/lib/twsapi` and the headers are located in `/usr/local/include/twsapi`.

To use that library in another project I have added `libtwsapi.a`under Build Settings > Link Binary With Libraries, and added `/usr/local/include` to the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATH` variable.

The build process fails during the linking part with the error message `ld: library not found for -twsapi` even though I have referenced the library. If I remove the link to the binary library I get lots of errors like `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:`, which makes sense since it cannot find the library in that case. This confirms the library was indeed found in the first place.

Any ideas what's going on? The arguments passed to the linker are shown below:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ \
  -arch i386 \
  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk \
  -L/Users/morten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_project-gwzyzroxzbyejngtpizlynumphvo/Build/Products/Debug \
  -L/usr/local/include \
  -L/usr/local/include/twsapi \
  -F/Users/morten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_project-gwzyzroxzbyejngtpizlynumphvo/Build/Products/Debug \
  -F/usr/local/lib \
  -filelist /Users/morten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_project-gwzyzroxzbyejngtpizlynumphvo/Build/Intermediates/test_project.build/Debug/test_project.build/Objects-normal/i386/test_project.LinkFileList \
  -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 \
  -stdlib=libc++ \
  -Xlinker \
  -dependency_info \
  -Xlinker /Users/morten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_project-gwzyzroxzbyejngtpizlynumphvo/Build/Intermediates/test_project.build/Debug/test_project.build/Objects-normal/i386/test_project_dependency_info.dat \
  -o /Users/morten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_project-gwzyzroxzbyejngtpizlynumphvo/Build/Products/Debug/test_project
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library is not being found. Your argument that "the library was indeed found in the first place" is faulty because the linker never gets to the point of listing undefined symbols - it halts upon not being able to find all specified libraries.

Your problem is in these arguments to the linker which specify additional paths to search for libraries:

```
-L/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/include/twsapi
```

Note that you are specifying a link path of /usr/local/*include* and not /usr/local/*lib* which is where your library is.

You need to add /usr/local/lib to the Library Search Paths in Xcode for linking. The Header Search Paths is used for compiling. From the log it appears that you have entries in both but the Library Search Paths entry is incorrect.

Comment: If I set `-L/usr/lib/include` and `-ltwsapi` I get the warning `ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libtwsapi.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libtwsapi.a` followed by lots of `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`. I am however, quite sure that the library was built for i386.

Comment: Your original problem appears solved because this is a different problem. Are you really sure that you built your external library for  i386 (32-bit) and not x86_64 (64-bit)? You can check your library from the command line with `lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libtwsapi.a` or `otool -hv -arch all /usr/local/lib/libtwsapi.a`.

Comment: Morten: you didn't compile the library in question for the i386 architecture.  You need to recompile with -m32 on gcc or -arch i386 in clang.