# When I try to run my Xcode project, it shows that linker error which I uploaded the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, testflight, zbar-sdk

I have a QR code reader project that uses Zbar SDK, but I get this error when I try to run it:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rweber/work/cornell_qr_reader/TestFlightSDK2.1.4'

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode linker error: ld: library not found for -twsapi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267730/xcode-linker-error-ld-library-not-found-for-twsapi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) after changing product name in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182257/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-after-changing)

Comment: how we can find weather it duplicated or not bcz this project is started by other developer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not properly put your third party library in your xcode bundle. Your library is not properly copied i think or some file is missing in library as warning shows that `directory not found`.

When drag and drop your library in xcode, you get a popup, in that `copy item if needed` and `add to targets` must be checked. and `create group` should be also checked.

Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182257/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-after-changing) it may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me its working

1. Click on your project in the left sidebar
2. Click 'Build Settings'
3. Go to 'Other Linker Flags'
4. Click 'Release'
5. Change the "-force_load" value from

   this `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/libCordova.a`

   to `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libCordova.a`

I hope its working for you

Comment: in my build settings in other linker flags has no paths its empty and there is no such after:${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libCordova.a file to add after this

Comment: than you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182257/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-after-changing